# Scala - how to set data into placeholder from config file?

Tags: scala, config

I have a simple `application.conf` file:

```
smth="smth ${data}"
```

The `data` is a placeholder which I would like to fill with some data given by te user. I read the `config` file, but I really have no idea how I can pass given data into this `String`. The only idea is to use `replace` on `String`, but I think it is not best solution:

```
def fill(arg: String) = {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").getString("smth")
  println(config.replace("${data}", arg))
}
```

Is it possible to write it in a cleaner way? I tried also to do some "magic" with string interpolation, but I failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is some workaround by %s?

```
smth="smth %s"


def fill(arg: String) = {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").getString("smth")
  println(config.format(arg))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to add an environment variable named `data` and then `resolve` the config with default `config-resolvers` which will pick up the environment variables.

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").resolve()
```

Other way is to provide a supplementary config, which can be used to resolve the placeholders,

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val resolveConfig = ConfigFactory.parseMap(Map("data" -> "abc").asJava).resolve()
```

Or,

```
val resolveConfig = ConfigFactory.parseString("""data: abc""").resolve()
```

Then use this to resolve your config,

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").resolve(resolveConfig)
```

Now, you can read your string from config,

```
val smthString = config.getString("smth")
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider [concatenation](https://github.com/lightbend/config#concatenation) in combination with programatically setting system properties before loading the config like so

```
smth="smth "${data}
```

and then

```
def fill(arg: String) = {
  System.setProperty("data", arg) // make sure to set before loading config
  val config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
  println(config.getString("smth") 
}
```

This way `${data}` gets substituted with `data` system property on load.